# Changing Skin File via C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I change the skin file  linked to asp.net page through the c# code?
I can change the stylesheet using:

```
HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
css.Href = "css/fancyforms.css";
css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
css.Attributes["media"] = "all";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
```

but what about skin file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can change the control skin by changing the `SkinId` property. Something like that:

```
css.SkinId = "MySkin";
```

Or if you have created a customized theme that contains `HtmlLink` control, then you can change the whole theme.

```
Page.Theme = "MyTheme";
```

Here is a good [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89(v=vs.140).aspx) article that shows how to do that.